# Search for two xml tags and return as a list of tuples in scala

Tags: xml, scala

I have code that currently does this:

```
val titles = (xml \\ "channel" \\ "item" \\ "title").map(_.text.trim)
val links  = (xml \\ "channel" \\ "item" \\ "link").map(_.text.trim)
val messages = titles zip links
```

but I have to join the two sequences together. Is there a way to search for the two tags together and have it return as the last line? Instead of having to zip the two sequences together?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking here, would the following solve the problem?

```
val items = xml \\ "channel" \\ "item"
items map {
  nodes => (textFor(nodes, "title"), textFor(nodes, "link"))
}

def textFor(ns: NodeSeq, tag: String) = (ns \\ tag) map (_.text.trim)
```